# Can we Do this type of array merge in PHP? If can, how?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

There are so many array functions out there, i tried couple of them even tried doing couple of looping.. i can't do it.
The given below array is my result array, same users are inserted multiple times because their values are different. Changing all the mechanism would be good idea, but iam at the last phase of the project. If anyone could do this, please reply:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
      (
        [user_id] => 321
        [name] => Paige Lycettok
        [id] => 4
        [openhouse_id] => 58e826747919f36c7cd0074d92af04c5
        [property_id] => 5
        [interested] => 1
        [openhouse] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 6e291b19bdca9a4d074976f0e8b9bcff
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-07
                        [start_time] => 08:00
                        [end_time] => 17:00
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => ca1927cee99722ac7fbd1a0588fdc4de
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-14
                        [start_time] => 07:00
                        [end_time] => 14:00
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 58e826747919f36c7cd0074d92af04c5
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 12:00
                        [end_time] => 18:00
                        [interested] => 1
                        [attendence] => 0
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 852e29abf3524a0b8ceea3ada823e44e
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 18:15
                        [end_time] => 21:15
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 1112019fed147e1de6f1308852009653
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-25
                        [start_time] => 09:15
                        [end_time] => 11:15
                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 03ab091ad03df06dfb6dcf2cb7ad211a
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-28
                        [start_time] => 03:15
                        [end_time] => 09:15
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => 320
        [name] => Mason Barker
        [id] => 5
        [openhouse_id] => 58e826747919f36c7cd0074d92af04c5
        [property_id] => 5
        [interested] => 1
        [openhouse] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 6e291b19bdca9a4d074976f0e8b9bcff
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-07
                        [start_time] => 08:00
                        [end_time] => 17:00
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => ca1927cee99722ac7fbd1a0588fdc4de
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-14
                        [start_time] => 07:00
                        [end_time] => 14:00
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 58e826747919f36c7cd0074d92af04c5
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 12:00
                        [end_time] => 18:00
                        [interested] => 1
                        [attendence] => 0
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 852e29abf3524a0b8ceea3ada823e44e
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 18:15
                        [end_time] => 21:15
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 1112019fed147e1de6f1308852009653
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-25
                        [start_time] => 09:15
                        [end_time] => 11:15
                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 03ab091ad03df06dfb6dcf2cb7ad211a
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-28
                        [start_time] => 03:15
                        [end_time] => 09:15
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => 323
        [name] => Jasmine Baudin
        [id] => 6
        [openhouse_id] => 03ab091ad03df06dfb6dcf2cb7ad211a
        [property_id] => 5
        [interested] => 1
        [openhouse] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 6e291b19bdca9a4d074976f0e8b9bcff
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-07
                        [start_time] => 08:00
                        [end_time] => 17:00
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => ca1927cee99722ac7fbd1a0588fdc4de
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-14
                        [start_time] => 07:00
                        [end_time] => 14:00
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 58e826747919f36c7cd0074d92af04c5
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 12:00
                        [end_time] => 18:00
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 852e29abf3524a0b8ceea3ada823e44e
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 18:15
                        [end_time] => 21:15
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 1112019fed147e1de6f1308852009653
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-25
                        [start_time] => 09:15
                        [end_time] => 11:15
                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 03ab091ad03df06dfb6dcf2cb7ad211a
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-28
                        [start_time] => 03:15
                        [end_time] => 09:15
                        [interested] => 1
                        [attendence] => 0
                    )

            )

    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => 323
        [name] => Jasmine Baudin
        [id] => 7
        [openhouse_id] => 852e29abf3524a0b8ceea3ada823e44e
        [property_id] => 5
        [interested] => 1
        [openhouse] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 6e291b19bdca9a4d074976f0e8b9bcff
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-07
                        [start_time] => 08:00
                        [end_time] => 17:00
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => ca1927cee99722ac7fbd1a0588fdc4de
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-14
                        [start_time] => 07:00
                        [end_time] => 14:00
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 58e826747919f36c7cd0074d92af04c5
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 12:00
                        [end_time] => 18:00
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 852e29abf3524a0b8ceea3ada823e44e
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 18:15
                        [end_time] => 21:15
                        [interested] => 1
                        [attendence] => 0
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 1112019fed147e1de6f1308852009653
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-25
                        [start_time] => 09:15
                        [end_time] => 11:15
                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 03ab091ad03df06dfb6dcf2cb7ad211a
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-28
                        [start_time] => 03:15
                        [end_time] => 09:15
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

In the above array, i have the same user_id: 323. What i want is if the user_id are same i want to merge their openhouse array into one just like below:

```
 Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
      (
        [user_id] => 321
        [name] => Paige Lycettok
        [id] => 4
        [openhouse_id] => 58e826747919f36c7cd0074d92af04c5
        [property_id] => 5
        [interested] => 1
        [openhouse] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 6e291b19bdca9a4d074976f0e8b9bcff
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-07
                        [start_time] => 08:00
                        [end_time] => 17:00
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => ca1927cee99722ac7fbd1a0588fdc4de
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-14
                        [start_time] => 07:00
                        [end_time] => 14:00
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 58e826747919f36c7cd0074d92af04c5
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 12:00
                        [end_time] => 18:00
                        [interested] => 1
                        [attendence] => 0
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 852e29abf3524a0b8ceea3ada823e44e
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 18:15
                        [end_time] => 21:15
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 1112019fed147e1de6f1308852009653
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-25
                        [start_time] => 09:15
                        [end_time] => 11:15
                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 03ab091ad03df06dfb6dcf2cb7ad211a
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-28
                        [start_time] => 03:15
                        [end_time] => 09:15
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => 320
        [name] => Mason Barker
        [id] => 5
        [openhouse_id] => 58e826747919f36c7cd0074d92af04c5
        [property_id] => 5
        [interested] => 1
        [openhouse] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 6e291b19bdca9a4d074976f0e8b9bcff
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-07
                        [start_time] => 08:00
                        [end_time] => 17:00
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => ca1927cee99722ac7fbd1a0588fdc4de
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-14
                        [start_time] => 07:00
                        [end_time] => 14:00
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 58e826747919f36c7cd0074d92af04c5
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 12:00
                        [end_time] => 18:00
                        [interested] => 1
                        [attendence] => 0
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 852e29abf3524a0b8ceea3ada823e44e
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 18:15
                        [end_time] => 21:15
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 1112019fed147e1de6f1308852009653
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-25
                        [start_time] => 09:15
                        [end_time] => 11:15
                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 03ab091ad03df06dfb6dcf2cb7ad211a
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-28
                        [start_time] => 03:15
                        [end_time] => 09:15
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => 323
        [name] => Jasmine Baudin
        [id] => 6
        [openhouse_id] => 03ab091ad03df06dfb6dcf2cb7ad211a
        [property_id] => 5
        [interested] => 1
        [openhouse] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 6e291b19bdca9a4d074976f0e8b9bcff
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-07
                        [start_time] => 08:00
                        [end_time] => 17:00
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => ca1927cee99722ac7fbd1a0588fdc4de
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-14
                        [start_time] => 07:00
                        [end_time] => 14:00
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 58e826747919f36c7cd0074d92af04c5
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 12:00
                        [end_time] => 18:00
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 852e29abf3524a0b8ceea3ada823e44e
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 18:15
                        [end_time] => 21:15
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 1112019fed147e1de6f1308852009653
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-25
                        [start_time] => 09:15
                        [end_time] => 11:15
                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 03ab091ad03df06dfb6dcf2cb7ad211a
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-28
                        [start_time] => 03:15
                        [end_time] => 09:15
                        [interested] => 1
                        [attendence] => 0
                    )
                [6] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 6e291b19bdca9a4d074976f0e8b9bcff
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-07
                        [start_time] => 08:00
                        [end_time] => 17:00
                    )

                [7] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => ca1927cee99722ac7fbd1a0588fdc4de
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-14
                        [start_time] => 07:00
                        [end_time] => 14:00
                    )

                [8] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 58e826747919f36c7cd0074d92af04c5
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 12:00
                        [end_time] => 18:00
                    )

                [9] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 852e29abf3524a0b8ceea3ada823e44e
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-21
                        [start_time] => 18:15
                        [end_time] => 21:15
                        [interested] => 1
                        [attendence] => 0
                    )

                [10] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 1112019fed147e1de6f1308852009653
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-25
                        [start_time] => 09:15
                        [end_time] => 11:15
                    )

                [11] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [openhouse_id] => 03ab091ad03df06dfb6dcf2cb7ad211a
                        [openhouse_date] => 2016-04-28
                        [start_time] => 03:15
                        [end_time] => 09:15
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

There can be multiple array with same user_id.

Comment: Can you port the `var_export()` result of your input array? It'll be much easier for us to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but you should be able to do this with relative ease.

If you use the `user_id` which I assume is unique as your array key, you will be able to easily access a user's data whenever you need to.

You have the added bonus of being able to *merge against existing keys* or simply create new ones if they don't exist.

For example:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($input as $values) {
    $userId = $values->user_id;
    if (array_key_exists($userId, $output)) {
        // We've already added this user, so merge in openhouse
        $output[$userId]->openhouse = array_merge($output[$userId]->openhouse, $values->openhouse);
    } else {
        // We haven't added it yet, so just add everything
        $output[$userId] = $values;
    }
}
```

**Now:** looking at your sample data it looks like your `openhouse` array contains the same set of data, with a couple of keys that exist in each array here and there differentiating them. If that's the case, you might want to use [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) instead. If you post a more usable example of your sample data I could have a play with it, but this should get you started.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need at open house ID or something you can cross reference with